# How to edit url without updating in browser - nginx config

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want the Request URL to be converted from
`http://host.com/newname/abc?def=` to
`http://newname/abc?def=`
here is the config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name
        host.com

location / {

    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.+)/index\.html$ $1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $1 permanent;

      try_files /$host/public/$uri @webserver;
      }
   }
```

Adding above line worked form me

```
location / {
            rewrite ^ $scheme://$request_uri? permanent; 
    }
```

But it replaces the url in user browser which i donn't want to happen.
Any way to achieve it

Comment: The question is where do you want to proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
location /newname{
  proxy_pass http://example.com/newname/abc?def=;
}
```

or

```
location /newname{
  proxy_pass http://newname/abc?def=;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ali-esmailpor But it replaces the url in user browser which i donn't want to happen.